# Some number theory problem which I want to check via Mathematica

Tags: number-theory

my Programming skills are quite horrendous (I don't work in the industry).
I want to check the following problem by programming in Mathematica, so I'd appreciate if someone can chime in and help me with this programming problem.

First for the two-digits problem, if we look at the number 17 if we multiply it by 2 we get 34, after adding and subtracting the digits of 34 we get back the digits of 17.
It seems there are no more such two digits numbers.
So now I am looking at 3 digits numbers when multiplied by 2 (or any other number), after adding and subtracting the digits we come back to the three digits of the number we started with before multiplying by 2.
For example, take the number 123, multiply it by 2 to get: 246, now adding and subtracting we get the following:
2+4+6=12
6-2+4=8
6-4+2=4
6-4-2=0
4+2-6=0
That's it if I am not wrong.
So I want to test for starters for three digits numbers, i.e 100 to 999.
How to implement this?
After that I'll know how to change the code for other n-digits numbers I believe.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why in you example you do not consider 2-4-6=-8 and 4-2-6=-4?

Comment: @yarchik you can consider them obviously but you wouldn't get the original digits either way.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear why you only made those five choices for combinations.  What about -6-4-2, for example?

Here's a procedure for calculating the result of all possible signs.

```
start = 123;
multiplier = 2;
signs = Table[
   2 PadLeft[IntegerDigits[n, 2], Length[IntegerDigits[start]]] - 1, 
   {n, 0, 7}];
sums = signs . IntegerDigits[multiplier start]

(* yields {-12, 0, -4, 8, -8, 4, 0, 12} *)
```

It's not clear how you want to process these results, though.  Take the `Abs`olute value, then the `Union`?  What do you do about the 12?

Let's assume you do want the `Union@*Abs`.  And tens digits should "carry" into the next digit.  Then you can use the inverse of `IntegerDigits`, `FromDigits`.

```
possibilities = FromDigits /@ Permutations[Union[Abs[sums]]]
(* {492, 528, 852, 924, 1248, 1284, 4092, ... *)
```

Since `MemberQ[possibilities, start]` is `False`, 123 doesn't satisfy (my interpretation of) your criterion.

Let's put this procedure into a `Module`.

```
satisfyingQ[start_, multiplier_] := Module[
  {
   digits = Length[IntegerDigits[multiplier start]],
   signs, sums, possibilities
   },

  signs = Table[
     2 PadLeft[IntegerDigits[n, 2], digits] - 1,
     {n, 0, 2^digits - 1}];
  sums = signs . IntegerDigits[multiplier start];
  possibilities = FromDigits /@ Permutations[Union[Abs[sums]]];
  MemberQ[possibilities, start]
  ]
```

Now `satisfyingQ[17,2]` is `True` and `satisfyingQ[123,2]` is `False`.

Which two digit numbers satisfy (my interpretation of) your criterion?

```
starts = Range[10, 99];
multipliers = Range[1, 10];
twoDigitTries = Flatten[Outer[List, starts, multipliers], 1];
Select[twoDigitTries, Apply[satisfyingQ]]
```

yields

```
{{17, 2},
 {34, 2},
 {35, 4},
 {70, 4}}
```

which suggests that my interpretation of what you're after isn't quite right.  But it all has to do with the carrying, I think, which you didn't specify clearly enough for me to know what to do.

Comment: If instead of carrying you want to throw away two-digit sums, you can do a `Select` on sums requiring that they be between 0 and 10.

Comment: what I wanted is to find out the three digits number that when multiplied by two and after that adding and subtracting the digits of the new number we get back the three digits of the original number. Is this now comprehensible?

Comment: No, I still think it's under-specified.  When you say digits, you mean by shuffling and gluing digits together?  Do you have to use all the resulting digits?  What do you do if a sum is greater than 9?

Comment: if a sum is greater than 9 then it doesn't qualify as a digit that's been in the original number.

Comment: You say there are no other 2-digit numbers beyond 17 that work with a multiplier of 2, but what about 71?  71*2=142.  4+2+1=7, 4-2-1=1.  There are so many choices, "what abouts", and "what ifs" that I'm going stop.  No choices I've made to these have produced 17 only.  I think you need to start playing around for yourself.